# Make git ignore rename

Tags: git, rename

I have a file `foo.txt` which I want to delete, and another, `bar.txt`, that I wish to add.  If these two files have more than 50% content that is the same, Git will consider that `foo.txt` is being renamed to `bar.txt`.  How can I make Git really see this as an individual remove, with an individual add, in the same commit, without changing the global threshold detection %.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason that it being logged as a "rename" is a problem?

Comment: The problem is that the two files should not have their history mingled.  Suppose I have a file titled `JohnDoe.txt` that contains John's work address and phone number of 555-555-1212.  John leaves the company at the same time as Jane Smith joins the company (creating file `JaneSmith.txt`).  Her work address is the same, but the phone number is 555-555-1313.  If the two add/rm are part of the same commit, Git will consider it a rename and `git log --follow` will tell me they were the same file (when I patently don't want them to be).  Suggestions?

Comment: @poke I'm not clear on how duplicate works.  My question was asked a year before the one you've identified.  Do you go by "most complete" answer?

Comment: @torngat The other question was previously closed pointing to this question, but I believe that the other question covers the resoning behind Git’s behavior a bit better so I inverted the direction (closing this question pointing to that other one instead). But don’t worry, a question being closed is generally not a bad thing. Your question is *still good* and will continue to lead people to the solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't. Internally, they will be saved as a deletion and an addition. The display of "rename" will be calculated later and depends on that threshold.

Answer (score 1):

To disable rename detection with *[TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)* (though as being git-diff option, should apply to git by itself as well) I added the following line to gitconfig, which seems to do the trick (although based on documentation, I don't think it should):

```
[diff]
  renameLimit = 1
```